# PHP Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: php, jquery

I have this PHP script and it does not work properly. What is the mistake?

```
<?php
if ( isset($success) || isset($failure) ) {
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.aler').css('display','block');
        $("div.aler").html("<?php if($success){echo '<p class=\"success\">'.$success.'</p>';} elseif($failure) {echo '<p class=\"failure\">'.$failure.'</p>';}; ?>");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("div.aler").fadeOut("slow", function (){
                $("div.aler").remove();
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
<?php }
```

I think there must be a problem with quotes:

```
" . $failure
```

has the message, but the JavaScript does not put it in HTML div:

```
div.aler
```

I get this error message in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: You have to double encode your quotes, `\\"`, so that the result contains `\"` for the JavaScript string. Look at the *generated* HTML and you will see.

Comment: Try escaping any `"` inside PHP like this `\\"` see what that does. Or change them to single quotes `'`. Or maybe even `\"`.

Comment: @FelixKling, It puts nothing to the div, so I can not check using html source. but I will give it a try using double encode my quotes. Thanks

Comment: @FelixKling I double encoded the `"` s but nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `isset` in below line, its required since your using "||" (OR) in your first if statement,
php throwing an error and thats breaking your javascript

```
$("div.aler").html( "<?php if( $success ){ echo '<p class=\"success\">'.$success.'</p>';}elseif($failure){echo '<p class=\"failure\">'.$failure.'</p>';}; ?>");
```

change this to...

```
$("div.aler").html( "<?php echo ( isset( $success ) ) ? '<p class=\"success\">'.$success.'</p>' : '<p class=\"failure\">'.$failure.'</p>'; ?>");
```

Comment: yeah and also dont forget to escape the success or failure message quotes, use 'addslashes'

Comment: Ye this clearly depends on wrong server settings. (display_error etc...) Voted up because I got the undefined variable error message, but I declared the variables after that. Did not know that it is possible to not debug something like that...

Answer (score 6):

The php output is not escaped for ", so instead of \" you have to use \\\" or \'.

Btw json_encode as a string would be much better...

```
$("div.aler").html(<?php
    if($success){
        echo json_encode('<p class="success">'.$success.'</p>');
    }
    elseif($failure){
        echo json_encode('<p class="failure">'.$failure.'</p>');
    };?>
);
```

Comment: @Arash The problem is with your copy-paste skills, not with this code. (I tested before I published.)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to put it into div.alert...yet in your code you wrote "div.aler"  you're missing a T...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.aler").html("<p class='<?=$success? 'success' : 'failure'?>'><?=$success? $success : $failure?></p>");
```

And of course escaping `$success` and `$failure` before output.